# Adding quotes to text in line using Python

Tags: python, replace, quotes, double-quotes

I am using Visual Studio Code to replace text with Python.
I am using a source file with original text and converting it into a new file with new text.

I would like to add quotes to the new text that follows. For example:

Original text: `set vlans xxx  vlan-id xxx`

New text: `vlan xxx  name "xxx"` (add quotes to the remaining portion of the line as seen here)

Here is my code:

```
    with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
        with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
            for line in fin:
                     line = line.replace('set vlans', 'vlan').replace('vlan-id', 'name')
                     fout.write(line)
```

Is there a way to add quotes for text in the line that follows 'name'?

Edit:

I tried this code:

```
    with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
    for line in fin:
     line = line.replace('set vlans', 'vlan').replace('vlan-id', 'name')
     words = line.split()
        words[-1] = '"' + words[-1] + '"'
        line = ' '.join(words)
     fout.write(line)
```

and received this error:

```
line 124, in <module>
words[-1] = '"' + words[-1] + '"'
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I also tried this code with no success:

```
    with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
    for line in fin:
    line = line.replace('set vlans', 'vlan').replace('vlan-id', 'name')
    
    import re
        t = 'set vlans xxx  vlan-id xxx'
        re.sub(r'set vlans(.*)vlan-id (.*)', r'vlan\1names "\2"', t)
        'vlan xxx  names "xxx"'
```

Again, my goal is to automatically add double quotes to the characters (vlan numbers) at the end of a line.

For example:

Original text: set protocols mstp configuration-name Building 2021.Rm402.access.mstp.zzz

Desired text: set protocols mstp configuration-name "Building 2021.Rm402.access.mstp.zzz"

Comment: You could try `split` to split the words based on whitespace and then add the quotes and then `join` them together again. Or, you can look into more commonly used methods like regular expressions

Comment: catch the whole line in a regex, and use a replace string with `\1` and `\2` to fill the capture groups, use the `re.sub()` method

Comment: @ProQ Would you be able to post an example of how that would look/work?

Comment: cesarv covered the regex one, so I'll show the split/join one. Sorry I didn't have the time to write a full answer at first - thus the comment

Comment: Also, just so you get used to using the site better, it helps if you add what you've already tried, or if you haven't tried anything, what pages you've looked at for resources. If you had this info, I would upvote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> t = 'set vlans xxx  vlan-id xxx'
>>> re.sub(r'set vlans(.*)vlan-id (.*)', r'vlan\1names "\2"', t)
'vlan xxx  names "xxx"'
```

The parentheses in the search pattern (first parameter) are used to create groups that can be used in the replacement pattern (second parameter). So the first `(.*)` match in the search pattern will be included in the replacement pattern by means of `\1`; same thing goes with the second one.

Edit:
The code I shared is just an example of how to use regular expressions. Here's how you should use it.

```
import re

# whatever imports and code you have down to...

with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin, open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
    for line in fin:
        line = re.sub(r'set vlans(.*)vlan-id (.*)', r'vlan\1names "\2"', line)
        fout.write(line)
```

IMPORTANT: if the format of the lines you need to modify is any different from the original text example you shared, you'll need to make adjustments to the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

First, we split the text up into words by splitting them by whitespace (which is what `split` does by default).

Then, we take the last word, add quotes to it, and join it back together with a space between each word:

```py
with open("SanitizedFinal_E4300.txt", "rt") as fin:
    with open("output6.txt", "wt") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.replace('set vlans', 'vlan').replace('vlan-id', 'name')
            words = line.split()
            # print(words)                     # ['vlan', 'xxx', 'name', 'xxx']
            if words: # if the line is empty, just output the empty line
                words[-1] = '"' + words[-1] + '"'
                line = ' '.join(words)
            # print(line)                      # vlan xxx name "xxx"
            fout.write(line)
```

WARNING: in your question, you say you'd like the output to be `vlan xxx  name "xxx"` which has **two** spaces after the first `xxx`. This result would only have one space between each word.

Comment: I tried this with no success. Would you be able to read the edit I made in the question and tell me where I went wrong? Using the example I gave would be great. Thank you.

Comment: @SammySaucer if you have an empty line in your file, you will have no words in the line, therefore [-1] will be an invalid index. Currently in class so will reply later to other things

Comment: Okay, I got out of class and have looked at things more closely; I think my above comment is correct. If you skip over empty lines or lines that aren't in the format you give in the question, I still believe my solution should work. You may also have a hidden newline at the end of your file. Again, skipping over empty lines should fix it. I'll change the code in my answer to update this.